# How to convert a text/plain HTTP POST request to JSON in CRUD?

Tags: node.js, json, express, http

I have a TCP server that sends post requests to an HTTP server:

```
const serverTcp = net.createServer( socket => {
    socket.on('data', data => {
        http.request(`http://${httpIp}:${process.env.PORT}/api/iotdata`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
        }).end(data.toString())
    })
}).listen(tcpPort)
```

The HTTP server catches it fine, but when I want to insert it in my mongo database, I get an "undefined" object and it inserts an empty object. I'm thinking it has to do with the request being in plain text and not in json, but I tried to convert it to JSON with JSON.parse or JSON.stringify and it doesn't work. (and in the future I would like to parse the request so should it be at the same place I'm converting it to json?)

```
const IotData = require('../models/IotData);

exports.createIotData = (req, res, next) => {
// should I convert it to json here?
  const newIotData = new IotData ({
    ...req.body
  })
  newIotData
  .save()
  .then(() => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message : 'IOT Data registered!',
      content : req.body
    })
  }).catch((error) => res.status(400).json({error}))
}
```

Just to make sure it had nothing to do with a mistake in parsing, I've made the mongoose model as simple as possible with only one argument that takes the whole request body:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const IotData = mongoose.model(
    'IotData ', new mongoose.Schema({
      all: String
  })
)

module.exports = IotData
```

Comment: Use the [`express.text()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.text) middleware to parse a `text/plain` request body into `req.body` (as a string).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen would adding it to the route like this work well? "router.post('/', express.text(), IotDataController.createIotData);" Or is it better to insert it in my function directly?

Comment: I recommend to include the middleware in the route(s) where it is needed, like you suggest.